# How to UPDATE a SQLITE Column with an INNER JOIN on TWO FIELDS

Tags: sqlite, java

How can I translate this query to SQLite:

```
UPDATE Table_1 
INNER JOIN Table_2 ON (Table_1.Field1 = Table_2.Field1) 
AND(Table_1.Field2 = Table_2.Field2)
SET Table_1.Field3 = Table_2.Field3
```

This is what I have tried.

```
UPDATE Table_1 
SET Field3 = (SELECT Field3
            FROM Table2
            WHERE (Field1 = Table_2.Field1)
            AND (Field2 = Table_2.Field2))
WHERE Field1 IN (SELECT Table_2.Field1
            FROM Table2
            WHERE (Field1 = Table_2.Field1)
            AND (Field2 = Table_2.Field2)) 
AND Field2 IN (SELECT Table_2.Field2
            FROM Table2
            WHERE (Field1 = Table_2.Field1)
            AND (Field2 = Table_2.Field2))
```

The query works but I get wrong results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to implement the join on two columns simultaneously, you can use an EXISTS predicate:

```
UPDATE Table_1 
SET Field3 = (SELECT Field3
              FROM Table_2
              WHERE (Table_1.Field1 = Table_2.Field1)
                AND (Table_1.Field2 = Table_2.Field2))
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM Table_2
              WHERE (Table_1.Field1 = Table_2.Field1)
                AND (Table_1.Field2 = Table_2.Field2));
```

If you are using [version 3.15.0](http://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_15_0.html) or later, you can also take advantage of [row value comparisons](http://sqlite.org/rowvalue.html):

```
UPDATE Table_1 
SET Field3 =
    (SELECT Field3
     FROM Table_2
     WHERE (Table_1.Field1, Table_1.Field2) = (Table_2.Field1, Table_2.Field2))
WHERE (Field1, Field2) IN (SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table_2);
```

Comment: Also: `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Field1, Field2 EXCEPT SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table_2) ;` (haven't tested it, not sure it works in SQLite) (or `EXISTS` - `INTERSECT`)